# Adding a text file to an application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been learning c# for a short time and am creating some desktop project. I would like to add an empty text file using RadWindow.Prompt its name and then add the text file for editing. Currently this is handled using openFileDialog.
The principle of operation should resemble adding a file in OneNote, if anyone has used it. RadWindow.Prompt will display a window in which the user will type the name of the file he wants to create and then the file will be added, but it will be an empty file for editing (text document).
I would ask for a hint.

```
private async void AddFile(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        bool response = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (response == true)
        {
            string filepath = openFileDialog.FileName;
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filepath);

            try
            {
                File.Copy(filepath, Settings[0].SettingValue + "\\" + fileName, true);
                long size = 1024;
                await _db.FileInsert(1, fileName, size, Settings[0].SettingValue + "\\" + fileName, "a", "FileAddTest", "FileAddTest");
                MessageBus.Default.Publish(new RefreshMessage(this, "Refresh"));
            }
            catch
            {
                RadWindow.Alert("File not add");
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "add" the file. You seem to open/create a file and then edit it. Of course, you would need to save your changes back to the file. But then what? If you want it to be attached to some kind of project or book or I don't know, you would need to save the path somewhere. Or you may chose to use a SQLite db as application file format and add files in there ... it's still rather broad and unclear, at least to me.

Comment: I am using mssql and adding a file via openFileDialog is writing correctly to the database, however it is still an existing file. I want to create an empty file addition, i.e. a window appears where the user enters a file name and it is added to the database, then he can edit it by entering some data, for example.

Comment: maybe....just maybe....you should add some code.....

Comment: I have added the code, however this is only my current solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of that, create model with for example two properties and add to DB context.

code concept:

```
class File
{
    public string FileName {get;set;}
    [Column(TypeName="text")]
    public string FileContent {get;set;}
}

void SomeAddFileButton()
{
    var file = new File()
    {
        FileName = someInputField.Text;
    };

    dbContext.Files.Add(file);
}
```

EF Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app

'text' type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql